# Setup Git without SSH

Tags: windows, git, ssh

We already had a secured VPN using OpenVPN, so we don't want to use Git with SSH to avoid double encryption.

I successfully set up [Bonobo Git Server](http://bonobogitserver.com/) on IIS 7 on Windows 2008 RC2 and created an repository. But when I tried to clone that repository from my laptop using Git GUI, it kept asking me username and password repetitively although I gave it the correct username and password created on Bonobo Server.

When I intentionally gave it incorrect credentials, it threw an expected authentication error.

Do you have any advice for me so I can connect to Git Server? Is it due to the lack of SSH keys?

Comment: If you have access to a shared folder, you can just set up a bare repository there and use that as the remote repository. There is no need for additional software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successful with [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)'s suggestion in his comment, which is utilizing a shared folder pointing to a remote bare repository.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, Bonobo offers three different authentication mechanisms: [Forms](http://bonobogitserver.com/forms-authentication/), [Basic](http://bonobogitserver.com/basic-authentication/), and [Windows](http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/) authentication. None of these involve SSH, so no, you are not using SSH and you don’t need SSH keys to make this work. SSH is just one mechanism that is commonly used for Git servers (simply because they run on Linux machines, and SSH access is very common there).

Bonobo uses the forms authentication by default. I believe you cannot preset the login information anywhere so you don’t have to enter it over and over again. You can do that with basic authentication though by changing the remote URL to include the credentials (e.g. `http://user:password@bonobo-server/project.git`). Of course, this will put the credentials in clear text into the repository’s configuration file, and also send the password in clear text over the network. The VPN connection will prevent someone outside of the VPN connection reading out that password, but inside of the VPN connection it is sent as clear text, so keep that in mind.

The more secure way would be Windows authentication. It uses your Windows login to authenticate at the server, and you won’t need to store your password somewhere. To Windows, it’s the “natural” authentication system, just like SSH is to Linux.

Comment: The one caveat with Windows Authentication is that you have to install Bonobo twice on IIS and mess about a bit.